# How to call 2 different paint methods in the same program?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paint

I'm trying to make a simple guess the number game and when the user guesses a number between a specific range from the actual answer it will draw a rectangle with a different colour. As of now i'm just testing and have created 2 paint methods and want to now how to call the method "paint2".

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MashGuessTheNumber extends Canvas {
    static Console c; // The output console

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Drawing");
        Canvas canvas = new MashGuessTheNumber();
        canvas.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        MashGuessTheNumber sm = new MashGuessTheNumber();
        c = new Console();
        int loop = 0;
        while (loop == 0) { // loop used to continue looping the questions after one is answered
            int answer = 0;
            c.println("Welcome to the guess the number game!");
            c.println("What is your name?");
            String name = c.readLine();
            c.print("why, hello there ");
            c.println(name);
            c.println("What diffuculty would you like to play?(easy/medium/hard)");
            String diff = c.readLine();
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("easy")) {
                // *Location of random number generator*
                c.println("So you chose easy, huh");
                c.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10");
                int guess = 1;
                answer = (int) (Math.random() * ((10 - 1) + 1));
                while (guess != answer) {
                    c.println("What is it?");
                    guess = c.readInt();
                    c.println(answer);
                    if ((((guess - answer) < 3) && ((guess - answer) > 0))
                            || (((answer - guess) < 3) && ((answer - guess) > 0))) {
                        c.println("EXTREMELY HOT");
                    }
                }
                if (guess == answer) {
                    c.println("You did it!");
                }

            }
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("medium")) {
                // *Location of random number generator*
                c.println("So you chose medium, huh");
                c.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100");
                c.println("What is it?");
                String guess = c.readLine();
                answer = (int) (Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1));
            }
            if (diff.equalsIgnoreCase("hard")) {
                // *Location of random number generator*
                c.println("So you chose hard, huh");
                c.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 1000");
                c.println("What is it?");
                String guess = c.readLine();
                answer = (int) (Math.random() * ((1000 - 1) + 1));
            }

            c.println("Would you like to play again?(y/n)"); // if answerd with "y" the loop will repeat
            String cont = c.readLine();
            if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                loop = 0;
            } else {
                for(int i=1;i<=24;i++){
                    c.println(" ");             
                c.setCursor(12, 30);
                c.println("See you next time. Bye!");
                loop = 1; // Stops the loop and says bye to the user
            }
        }
        // Place your program here. 'c' is the output console
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int x[] = { 35, 75, 75, 35 };
        int y[] = { 10, 10, 200, 200 };
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int numberofpoints = 4;
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, numberofpoints);
    }

    public void paint2(Graphics g) {
        int x[] = { 35, 75, 75, 35 };
        int y[] = { 10, 10, 200, 200 };
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        int numberofpoints = 4;
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, numberofpoints);
    }
    // main method
} // MashGuessTheNumber class
```

I'm just trying to draw a different rectangle as of now over top the first one whenever I want and if there is another way that doesn't use two methods that would also be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where you call paint() at all, but I would make a second parameter that would act as a flag telling me whether to draw a blue or black rectangle. This would get rid of repeated code.

```
public void paint (Graphics g, Color color)
{
    int x[] = {35, 75, 75, 35};
    int y[] = {10, 10, 200, 200};
    g.setColor (color);
    int numberofpoints = 4;
    g.drawPolygon (x, y, numberofpoints);
}
```

I don't know if 'Color' is the correct object to use to pass in a color, but the point is to pass in something that will help you choose what color to make the rectangle so that way you don't have to write two very similar methods. You will call paint() like this:

```
if(some condition) {
    paint(g, Color.blue);
}
else {
    paint(g, Color.black);
}
```

Comment: @HamiClash let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to call the method in the main method, but it does not work?

Comment: Where did you put the paint method that you dont have access to it?

Comment: In the Java Swing framework, the paint method is called by the framework and not the user.

Answer (score -1):

In the Java Swing framework, you don't call Canvas.paint() yourself. But, you can use your own intance variables.

If you add an instance variable to your MashGuessNumber class

```
private Color myColor = Color.BLACK;
```

Then modify your if statement

```
if (count == answer) {
    System.out.println("You did it1);
    myColor == Color.BLUE;
    repaint();              // already a Canvas method
}
```

Then modify your paint() method

```
public void paint (Graphics g, Color color)
{
    int x[] = {35, 75, 75, 35};
    int y[] = {10, 10, 200, 200};
    g.setColor (myColor);
    int numberofpoints = 4;
    g.drawPolygon (x, y, numberofpoints);
}
```

This should do the trick.

The call to repaint() tells Swing to redraw the canvas by calling your paint() method. Otherwise the system would have no way of knowing that your Canvas needs to be redrawn.

Comment: May I ask why my answer was downvoted? I'd like to improve my answers.